# Android UIAutomator Testing: Count of all elements present in the list view

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

While doing mobile UI Automation testing using Android UIAutomator, I need to find out all the elements present in the list view.

By using 'getChildCount()' method as shown below, I am getting the count of currently visible elements **only**, but more elements are present in the list view but are invisible.

Here is the sample code:

```
    //Created UI Object for list view
UiObject listview_elements = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.ListView"));


//Printing the numbmer of child ements present in the List View by using getchildCount() method
System.out.println("List view elements : "+listview_elements.getChildCount());*
```

Could any one kindly help to get the count of all **list view** elements including **invisible** elements (i.e currently not displayed on the screen).

**Note:** 
Kindly note that here I am not implementing android UI, rather I am just testing the third party android app's UI using Android's UIAutomator.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but here are some suggestions.

Remember that you can use UI Automator Viewer to identify resource ids and such.
*AndroidSDKPath\tools\uiautomatorviewer*

A couple considerations that change how we approach this.

- Are items in the list clickable?
- Are items in the list the same size?
- Do the items contain distinct text fields?

Assuming the items in the list are clickable you can use a selector like this:

```
UiSelector selector = new UiSelector().clickable(true);
```

If the items do contain distinct text fields then you can perhaps use a Java *Set* to keep track of strings that represent each item.

If the items in the list are the same size then you can use a loop and scroll up by the same amount each time. Otherwise you can look at the next item in the list, get its bounds, get the top coordinate, and then scroll upward until you reach the top of the list (this might be the bottom of a toolbar). You can check if you hit the top by looking at the bounds.

When writing a loop the idea would be to only increment the index if you reach the end of the list since when you scroll up the top most item will become position 0.

Your loop would look something like this:

```
//UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());;
UiObject list = device.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(PACKAGE + ":id/" + resourceId));

int index = 0;
int count = 0;

while (index < list.getChildCount()) {
    UiObject listItem = list.getChild(selector.index(index));

    Set<String> examinedItems = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    //if first item is a bit out of view (under toolbar) then skip it
    if (listItem.getBounds().top < TOOLBAR_BOTTOM_Y) {
        index++;
        continue;
        //this will only ever happen once = reached end of list
    }

    //get unique details from each item
    //for example, you might get a text field for that list item list this
    //UiObject textField = listItem.getChild(new UiSelector().resourceId(PACKAGE + ":id/" + childResourceId));
    String itemDetails = ...;

    //this would be relevent if the list was perfectly scrolled to the top and we don't know we are at the end of the list
    if (examinedItems.contains(itemDetails)) {
        index++;
        continue;
    }

    //do any actual testing on the item here..
    count++;

    //if index > 0 we have reached the end of the list
    if (index == 0) {
        //you'll need to inherit from InstrumentationTestCase so you can pass an instance to this method
        TouchUtils.drag(this, CENTER_X, CENTER_X, START_SCROLL_Y, START_SCROLL_Y - ITEM_HEIGHT, 150);
    }

    examinedItems.add(itemDetails);
}

//maybe return count here
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is of uniform size, (you know how tall each individual view is) you could do the following:

First get the ListView as a [UiScrollable](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiScrollable.html).

Call scrollToBeginning() to start at the top of the ListView.

Call getChildCount() to get the number of children on screen

scrollForward() until the bottom view is no longer visible.

Call getChildCount() again and repeat the process until you're at the bottom of the view.

You could find out how many swipes you need to do in order to get to the bottom by performing one such swipe, then seeing if scrollToEnd() returned false, (it was already at the bottom). If scrollToEnd() returned true, you would need to scroll back to the top and start over, this time increasing the amount of swipes you do by one. If you need to verify that a single element is in the listview (as this method of determining length & swiping through would be very slow) you could always use the getChildBy...() methods.

Comment: this will not work, because after you do scrollForward, there is no way to tell how many list items it has scrolled forward, so you cannot tell if you missed any or if it is counting list items that it already counted in the previous getChildCount call

Comment: @Andrew It is hard and not easy to get the number of scrolls on forward. Do you have a trial code snippet